# Was the 4-legged thing the scavenger was riding an animal or a robot?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In *The Force Awakens*, there is a desert scavenger netting a droid while riding a four-legged mount, which to me at first seemed to be wearing metal (armor?) but then by the way it walked, I assumed was a robot equivalent of a riding animal.

Was that a robot designed like an animal, or an animal that looked like a robot, or something else?

Comment: Sheesh. Two answers, and neither starts off correctly. *If both parts of an "or" question turn out to be correct, the answer is not "both", it's **"YES"**.* Harumph.

Comment: @Martha feel free to add your own answer, or suggest an edit.

Comment: @Martha I would say the correct answer should then be “no”. It would only be “yes” if only one of the options is correct.

Comment: @phantom42: I'm kidding. Well, kinda. I think you both missed a prime opportunity to use my favorite math-geek "joke", but I'm not actually, like, upset. :) *(Mom sends her computer-geek offspring to the store: "Bring me a bottle of milk, and if they have eggs, bring me half a dozen." Offspring comes home with six bottles of milk.)*

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: that's exclusive-or, which would be an incorrect interpretation in 99.99% of real life cases. Unless your family goes around saying "xor", which would be kind of cool, but highly unusual.

Comment: @Martha Depends entirely on the context. In a question like “Is Thing X and A, a B, or a C?”, I would instinctively interpret the _or_ as exclusive. Seeing it as _xor_ is no more likely to be incorrect than interpreting an _or_ question as a yes/no question; answering the question “Are you drunk or not?” in the affirmative if you're sober is every bit as unlikely to be correct.

Comment: @Martha I got your kinda-joke, if that helps. (Even if it doesn't help.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, I wouldn't answer "are you [X] or not" with "yes". It's for questions like "would you like something to eat or drink?" If you're both hungry and thirsty, instead of explaining "I'd like both, please" (because that would use too many words for a true math geek to utter all at once), you just answer "yes". It's also good for impossible choices: "Do you want chocolate or bacon?" "Uh... yes please?"

Comment: @Martha, Martha, Martha... This is scifi.SE, not ELU.

Comment: [i get it. i ain't laughing, but i get it.](http://cdn.meme.am/instances/400x/65493723.jpg)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### A bit of both, actually.

The Luggabeast is a cybernetic mount used on Jakku.

From [The Star Wars Databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/luggabeast)

> **Luggabeast**
>
> Cybernetic beasts of burden found on frontier worlds, luggabeasts are a fusion of organic being and mechanical creation, with their heads hidden away behind heavy armor plating and optical instruments. Jakku’s Teedos use luggabeasts as pack animals, calibrating the cyborg creatures’ instruments to find droids and other valuable salvage.

The design actually comes more from wanting to use a certain type of puppeteering technology.

From *The Art of The Force Awakens*:

> We were talking to Brian Herring, who is our puppet-performers guy, about the stage play *War Horse*. "What can we do that uses that technology?" Again, with the beauty of digital technology, we do have the potential for rod removal, leg removal. How far can we push it?"

[image: Teedo on a Luggabeast with Rey and BB-8]

Comment: Ninjaed you :))

Comment: That's what I get for taking the extra minute to check the art book.

Comment: OK, you win. Art book beats novelization :) +1

Answer (score 8):

It's called a **luggabeast** and it is BOTH.

We know what it's called from Foster's novelization:

> Reaching the top of a nearby dune, she found herself gazing down at a sight as curious as it was unexpected. Trapped in a net of local organic material, a small spherical droid was attempting to escape its prison, an effort rendered extremely difficult by the fearful mechanical’s total absence of limbs. Mounted atop a squat, four-footed, square-helmeted **luggabeast**, a native Teedo was struggling to constrain and reel in the legless but overactive and insubordinate droid.

[Star Wars Databank](http://www.starwars.com/databank/luggabeast) says this:

> **Cybernetic beasts of burden found on frontier worlds, luggabeasts are a fusion of organic being and mechanical creation, with their heads hidden away behind heavy armor plating and optical instruments**. Jakku’s Teedos use luggabeasts as pack animals, calibrating the cyborg creatures’ instruments to find droids and other valuable salvage.

Here's the image from Commando game (its use in military may explain the need for armor)

[image]